# Feedme Only running Cron jobs when logging in

Tags: plugin-feedme, craft4

I've created a cron job that runs my Feedme feeds on an hourly basis. The issue is, when logging in I see all the jobs queued up, but they only start running when I actually login to the dashboard, is there something I'm missing here?

Here's the cronjob:

```
@hourly wget -q -O - "https://feedmefeed.com/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task&direct=1&feedId=4&passkey=pass"
@hourly wget -q -O - "https://feedmefeed.com/index.php?p=actions/feed-me/feeds/run-task&direct=1&feedId=5&passkey=pass"
```

Is there something that's required to make it run automatically instead of queueing and awaiting me to login to the `/admin` area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Craft queue jobs are only run when someone logs into the CP. Your cron job is triggering Feed Me to create the queue jobs, but the jobs themselves won't be run until you log in.

There are a few ways to get around this - you could have a cron job that triggers the Craft `queue/run` console command on a regular schedule, or you can use Oliver Stark's [Async Queue](https://github.com/ostark/craft-async-queue) plugin to ensure that queue jobs are run as soon as they're pushed to the queue.

I recommend you check out nystudio107's excellent article [Robust Craft Queue Job Handling](https://nystudio107.com/blog/robust-queue-job-handling-in-craft-cms) for more info on these and other solutions to allow your queue jobs to run automatically.